# Getting listener timeout after waiting for [10000] ms from ElasticsearchIO

Tags: java, elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to test a simple Apache Beam code with source as Elasticsearch. I found the ElasticsearchIO source class from the [git repo](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch).

I modified Beam's MinimalWordCount example to include source as Elasticsearch instead of TextIO. Below is the gist,

```
String[] hosts = new String[1];
hosts[0]="http://localhost:9200";
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(
      ElasticsearchIO.read().withConnectionConfiguration(
        ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration.create(hosts, "test_index", "users").withUsername("esuser").withPassword("password")
      )
 )
.apply("ExtractWords", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
         for (String word : c.element().split("[^a-zA-Z']+")) { 
           if (!word.isEmpty()) {
             c.output(word);
           }
         }
      }
}));
p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

If I run the code by,

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.MinimalWordCount \
 -Pdirect-runner
```

I am getting error

> An exception occured while executing the Java class. null:
>   InvocationTargetException: java.io.IOException: listener timeout after
>   waiting for [10000] ms

I debugged [ElasticsearchIO.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.java) and could see everything works fine, the Elasicsearch client is built & data from index is being retrieved by the code. But ParDo function after read transform does not get executed at all. The Elasticsearch client keeps waiting and finally gets a timeout error.

I know the Elasicsearch connector for Beam is still under development. But can anyone help out in finding what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am running Elasticsearch 5.2.1 locally.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of ElasticsearchIO (beam-0.6.0 2017/03) does not support yet the version 5 of Elasticsearch. Progress on this is tracked by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1637

Answer (score 1):

The timeout problem is indeed due to an incompatibilty of the current Elasticsearch IO with ES v5.x. But not clearing the scroll has a cost at the ES side: the segments merging process (create bigger segments out of smaller ones and delete smaller ones) is hold because ES cannot delete old segments while they are in use by the scroll context.

Besides, another thing: the IO.read returns documents as Json, so the split ParDo might also split on field names not only field values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run mvn -X to get detailed description? 
I found on the elastic forum this 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es5-indexing-performance-seems-slow/65084/22
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es5-correct-restclient-failurelistener-behaviour-retry-logic/68211/3

You should maybe investigate more through the timeout

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the code performing delete scroll. If I comment that code in ElasticsearchIO.java, the pipeline runs fine.

```
restClient.performRequest(
             "DELETE",
             "/_search/scroll",
             Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
             entity,
             new BasicHeader("", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue directly covering the exception received, titled "[Getting listener timeout after waiting for [10000] ms from ElasticsearchIO](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1688)", has been recently closed with message: "It was solved by adding ES 5.x support (https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3703)".

Does the error still manifest itself now?